# Change text align when col level is reached in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

- I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and I want to change the text alignment to Left when col-sm-6 is reached. If this level is not reached yet then the text alignment is right. How can I do that?

Below is my div:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 text-right" style="padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:10px" >
   <a class="BAN_ForgotPass" href="#">Forgot the password ?</a>
</div>
```

I have tried to add this in the script css in the header but didn't work:

```
 <style type="text/css"> 
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            footer .text-right { text-align:left }
        }    
 </style>
```

Any suggestions?

- Another question please: is there anyway to detect in javascript or jquery if col level was reached? I am asking this because sometimes we need to hide images or add somthing in some levels ... 
  For example: hide image x when col-sm-6 is reached. Is it possible?

Comment: Where is the `<footer>` ?

Comment: You don’t need JavaScript to hide or show elements at certain breakpoints - Bootstrap has helper classes for that, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Your phrase "when col-sm-6 is reached" is not clear. What exactly is the behavior you want to see? Is it based on the screen width (for which an @media rule will be fine) or on the position of the element within a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the correct bootstrap HTML then this should work

```css
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .container .text-right {
    text-align: left
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
      <a class="BAN_ForgotPass" href="#">Forgot the password ?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To answer your second question, about hiding elements you can use [utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) in this case `hidden-sm` and `hidden-xs`

Comment: Solved now, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this below code

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
            .text-right { text-align:left; }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this into your page with inline CSS and if works fine make external CSS

```
       .col-sm-6
{
text-align:left;
}
```

if this works make a Separate CSS for each changes you want 
like for image hide add below line in above code

```
  .col-sm-6
{
text-align:left;
diaplay : block;
}
```